# vertically center span (bootstrap label) together with other elements

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I'd like to use the inline labels of the bootstrap css framework:

```
<span class="label">Default</span>
```

Unfortunately these labels are not vertically centered when used together with other elements.

```
<p>
  <span class="label"><a href="#">test</a></span>This is a test heading.
</p>
```

Please see the full code for a visual example: http://jsfiddle.net/kvPpm/

I am aware of the line-height and absolute/relative positioning workarounds but was not able to apply them correctly.

How can I vertically center these labels?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `<span>` is an `inline` element by default you can just do:

```
span { vertical-align: middle|top|bottom; }
```

And it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/kvPpm/1/

But then `<a>` inside `<span>` is not semantically correct. You can just use `<a>` and style it `display: inline`.

http://jsfiddle.net/kvPpm/3/

Answer (score 2):

```
.label { vertical-align: top; }
```

This worked for me when I wanted it to be aligned properly in a ul